# Как записать в переменную текст ошибки консоли?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, консоль

Допустим, я делаю `ajax` запрос на несуществующую страницу в интернете. В консоле сразу появится следующая строка

```
GET http://blablablablabla22.com/index.php net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED jquery.min.js:6
```

Как ее можно, и можно ли вообще, записать в переменную чтобы вывести например в блоке `div`? Спасибо.

Comment: "Её" - это что? Ошибку?

Comment: Да, именно эту ошибку, такого вида как в консоле.

Comment: Именно как в консоли нельзя, поскольку это сообщение принадлежит браузеру и JS не имеет к нему никакого отношения и доступа. Для JS используется другой вид перехвата ошибок и тексты:  как уже показали на примере использования error в $.ajax. За доп.сведения и описанием можно обратиться к документации: [jquery ajax settings](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте через `error`

```
$.ajax({
    type:     "post",
    data:     {id: 0},
    cache:    false,
    url:      "doIt.php",
    dataType: "text",
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
      alert(err.Message);
    },
    success: function () {
        alert(" Done ! ");
    }
});
```

Comment: Выдает "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Message' of undefined"

Comment: @2849141 попробуйте `console.log(err)` и покажите в вопросе, может узнаем в чем проблема в вашем случае

Comment: А зачем вы используете `eval`?

Comment: console.log(err) -> undefined